# How can I execute 2 separate queries using PDO and send back the resultant array to javascript

Tags: php, javascript, mysql, ajax

```
$data = $dbh->prepare('SELECT workloadformula,coursecode FROM coursedetails WHERE coursecode = ' . $dbh->quote($coursecode) . ' ; select concat(firstname," ",lastname) as name from lecturerdetails where concat(firstname," ",lastname) = ' . $dbh->quote($name) . '');


$data->execute();
do {
    $result = $data->fetchAll();
    $final  = var_dump($result);
    echo "$final";
} while
(
    $dbh->nextRowset()
);
```

Comment: nice advice. I have already tried to make joins but the ids of those tables are different and will not match. is this what you are trying to tell "Use Join" ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming `$dbh` is an instance of the `PDO` class:

1. There's no such method as `PDO::nextRowset()`, you probably meant `$data->nextRowset()`.
2. `var_dump()` doesn't return anything, so assigning the result to `$final` is meaningless.

Comment: ok I understand now, thank you. Is there any way to execute 2 queries and echo the results using PDO ?

Comment: Query twice, echo twice. That's pretty much all there is to it.

Comment: $data = $dbh->prepare('SELECT workloadformula,coursecode FROM coursedetails WHERE coursecode = ' . $dbh->quote($coursecode));
$data ->execute();  
  $workloadformula = $data->fetchall();
  echo "$workloadformula";

// then

$data = $dbh->prepare(select concat(firstname," ",lastname) as name from lecturerdetails where concat(firstname," ",lastname) = ' . $dbh->quote($name) . '' );
$data ->execute();
$name = $data->fetchall();
echo "$name";